# How can I Tween an element to the right without pushing the page edge?

Tags: css, gsap

I have a logo that is made up of 4 circles. My HTML has these as separate circles and what I'm trying to do is this...

When the page loads all the circles start centered and overlapped. Immediately an animation expands the circles to the left and right so that they only slightly overlap. The problem is that the elements that get moved to the right push the edge of the page off to the right so the user could scroll to the right and see nothing but whitespace.

I'm using the TweenMax library.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo_circles" id="logo1"><img src="img/logo_01.png"></div>
    <div class="logo_circles" id="logo3"><img src="img/logo_03.png"></div>
    <div class="logo_circles" id="logo2"><img src="img/logo_02.png"></div>
    <div class="logo_circles" id="logo4"><img src="img/logo_04.png"></div>
</div>
```

And the matching CSS...

```
.logo_circles {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.logo_circles img {
    width:250px;
    height:auto;
    opacity:0.8;
}

/* Set height adjustments */
#logo2, #logo3, #logo4 {
    margin-top:-250px;
}

/* set horizontal position adjustments */
#logo1 {
    margin-left:-600px;
}

#logo2 {
    margin-left:-200px;
}

#logo3 {
    margin-right:-200px;
}

#logo4 {
    margin-right:-600px
}
```

Comment: It would be good to please see your JS TweenMax code you have already tried, to better help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is getting pushed to the far right with the scroll bar, because you will need to use **position: absolute** on your **.logo_circles** elements, which will take your elements out of the flow of the document.. so it doesn't affect your markup around the logo.

```
.container {
     position:relative;
}

.logo_circles {
    position:absolute;
}
```

And to use the CSS properties top, right, bottom, left instead of margin-right and margin-top. Or use translateX() and/or translateY to position the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use the css padding properties instead of margin...

```
.logo_circles {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.logo_circles img {
    width:250px;
    height:auto;
    opacity:0.9;
}

/* Set height adjustments */
#logo2, #logo3, #logo4 {
    margin-top:-250px;
    /*width:250px;*/
    /*margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;*/
}

/* set horizontal position adjustments */
#logo1 {
    /*margin-right:auto;*/
    /*width:250px;*/
    /*margin:0 auto;*/
    padding-right:600px;
}

#logo2 {
    padding-right:200px;
}

#logo3 {
    padding-left:200px;
}

#logo4 {
    padding-left:600px;
}
```

Then the updated Tween calls are...

```
TweenMax.from($('#logo1'), 2, {css:{paddingLeft:0, paddingRight:0}, ease:Quad.easeInOut, delay:2 });
TweenMax.from($('#logo2'), 2, {css:{paddingLeft:0, paddingRight:0}, ease:Quad.easeInOut, delay:2 });
TweenMax.from($('#logo3'), 2, {css:{paddingLeft:0, paddingRight:0}, ease:Quad.easeInOut, delay:2 });
TweenMax.from($('#logo4'), 2, {css:{paddingLeft:0, paddingRight:0}, ease:Quad.easeInOut, delay:2 });
```